# Cut a vector and automatically encompas the tail or further extremes?

Tags: r

Here's a data frame:

```
x <- data.frame(
  blah = letters[1:6],
  y = c(1,2.2,3,4.3,5.5,8)
)
```

If I then add some bins using cut:

```
x %>% mutate(z = cut(y, 0:5))
```

Results in:

```
  blah   y     z
1    a 1.0 (0,1]
2    b 2.2 (2,3]
3    c 3.0 (2,3]
4    d 4.3 (4,5]
5    e 5.5  <NA>
6    f 8.0  <NA>
```

Those NA values. I would like to tell r to use the largest bin to be from, in this case, 5 to 8 because 5 is the largest value in my input vector for bins.

Is there a way to automatically encompass the outlying values from the input vector? i.e. I would like the data cut in increments of 1 up till 5, then just one bin for everything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
x %>% mutate(z = cut(y, c(0:5, max(y))))
#   blah   y     z
# 1    a 1.0 (0,1]
# 2    b 2.2 (2,3]
# 3    c 3.0 (2,3]
# 4    d 4.3 (4,5]
# 5    e 5.5 (5,8]
# 6    f 8.0 (5,8]
```